# How to change the cloudwatch agent logging region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have successfully installed cloudwatch agent in amazon linux instance and configured the awslogs.conf file as below.But unfortunately the loggroup is created in us-east-1 instead of configured region us-east-2.Any idea what mistake i'm doing?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Manually create or edit the CloudWatch agent configuration file - Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html) -- see the mention of **Region**.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your AWS profile region. This must be because of the current default region is selected as us-east-2. Try run `aws configure` command and change your region to the desired one.